# Magento htaccess Search Result Rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento, mod-rewrite

We have a magento cart that retrieves search queries using the following.

http://www.example.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=firstparam+otherparam+stuff

We'd like it to serve it via:
http://www.example.com/firstparam+otherparam+stuff

None of our current rules seem to work.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} q=(.*)
RewriteRule ^/?q/(.*?)/?$ /catalogsearch/result/?q=$1 [R=301,L]
```

We have tried various iterations of all of them, but to no avail.

Comment: `+` has special meaning in query string it represents space. It would be better if you use `-` instead. Or you can just encode it before appending to query string.

Comment: Hello @Stech, Have you found solution of above. Please share here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+catalogsearch/result/\?q=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /q/%1? [L,NE,R=301]

RewriteRule ^q/(.*)$ /catalogsearch/result/?q=$1 [L,NE,QSA]
```

Comment: That provides http://www.domain.com/q/firstparam+otherparam+stuff
But it 404s and does not run the search.

Comment: @user2196976 does going to `http://www.domain.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=firstparam+otherparam+stuff` work for you? Did you place the htaccess file in your site's document root?

Comment: Yes, the root works fine.  I suspect this is not going to work, as Magento does custom rewrites to get to that "/catalogsearch/result/?q=firstparam+otherparam+stuff".